# How much capacity is good for an iPad? Does one need 3G on it?

Tags: ipad, hardware-recommendation

My iPod Touch (8GB) always bothers me with lack of free space. And right now I'm considering buying the new iPad and would like to choose the right storage capacity. I'm trying to decide between 32 GB and 64 GB. Will 32 GB be short for anyone? Why?

Also, does one really need 3G on their iPad? I have a 3G phone (Android) which let's me create a hotspot for free. That's when on the move but most of the time I'm assuming I'll be in a Wifi enabled area. So is it right for me to not get 3G? Or are there scenarios that I'm missing? (I know I'll be using my phone's *and* iPad's batter when I'll tether.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm absolutely fine with a 32GB WiFi only iPad. 32GB is enough for most of my music, audio books, all the apps I use and some tv episodes. I never missed 3G on my iPad. Just one thing: you won't have GPS without 3G. If you have an iPhone, you can tether both, data and coordinates via WLAN (not bluetooth as previously said).

Comment: It was in the news the last days, that GPS can be shared by the personal hotspot in iOS 4.3. I just read, that this is not possible. So maybe it works, maybe it doesn't...

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to store videos on it and your whole music collection then go with either the 32GB or the 64GB. If you just going to use apps on it and do some reading then 16GB will be enough for you.

I have the 32GB Wifi iPad since this summer and I still have about 15GB of empty storage. I also have an android phone with 3G data and tethering and I am quite happy with it. So 3G is not needed.

I think the best is to choose the middle road and have a 32GB wifi iPad.

Answer (score 1):

64 gigs is nice if you're on the road for extended periods and want to take several dozen movies along.
In the US, there are enough free wifi hotspots around so that, in town, you'll never lack for places where you can create a route map. It just takes a little more planning than with 3G.